# Why doesn't my method return anything even though I have print statements?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, method-call

When I attempt to call the daysInaMonth method in my main method, I get this error:

```
DaysInMonth.java:34: error: missing return statement
   }
   ^
1 error
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Why isn't the method call working? I've made sure that both methods return the correct data type. Here is my class file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class DaysInMonth { 

   public String daysInaMonth (int year_number, String month_name) {
      if(year_number % 4 != 0 || month_name != "February") {
         switch(month_name) {
            case "January":
            case "March":
            case "May":
            case "July":
            case "August":
            case "October":
            case "December":
                System.out.print("31");
               break;
            case "April":
            case "June":
            case "September":
            case "November":
                System.out.print("30");
               break;
            case "February":
               System.out.print("28");
               break;
            default:
               System.out.print("Please input ");
               break;
         }  
      }
      else {
           System.out.print("29");
      }

   }


   public String main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   String month = " ";
   int year = 0;

   month = scnr.nextLine();

   year = scnr.nextInt();

   return daysInaMonth(year, month);


   }


}
```

Comment: -: public String daysInaMonth (int year_number, String month_name) this right here is hungry for string value.

Comment: The answer here: this is super basic stuff. Turn to your learning material and study! It also very much helps to Google for your error message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a basic, simple error that could be easily resolved by doing just a little bit of prior research.

Comment: Just put the words "java missing return statement" into Google... And the fact that other not so great questions see upvotes... Yes. That happens. But doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `daysInaMonth()` method doesn't return anything. The signature says it should return a `String`.

However, the method is currently setup to do printing, not to return `String`s.

## First Option: Keep It as a Printing Method

So, the easiest would be to change the signature of your method to:

```
public void printDaysInAMonth (int year_number, String month_name) {
     // ... your code ...
}
```

Then, in `main()`, instead of doing:

```
return System.out.print(daysInAMonth(year, month));
```

Just do:

```
printDaysInAMonth(year, month);
```

## Second Option: Return Something

In `daysInaMonth()`, change every reference to `System.out.print()` to a return statement, to return the `String`. Also remove `break`, which will no longer be useful since you are `return`ing. Example:

```
        case "December":
            return "31";
```

Now in `main()`, you can call the `daysInaMonth()` and it will return the `String` value:

```
String stringThatWeGotBack = daysInaMonth(year, month);
System.out.println(stringThatWeGotBack);
```

Or just:

```
System.out.println(daysInaMonth(year, month));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `System.out.print` to `return` statement inside `daysInaMonth` method.

Also, change  `return daysInaMonth(year, month);` to `System.out.print(daysInaMonth(year, month))` in main method.